# Why is the all method defined in ActiveRecord::Base not listed in the documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is the `all` method defined in `ActiveRecord::Base` not listed in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)?

I know it is defined here because I ran `Post.method(:all).source_location` and got this output:

```
["/Users/space/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb",
 440]
```

Comment: Funny enough, the `all` method is _mentioned_ in the [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) method description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's defined by the `delegate` "macro" and the documentation generator isn't aware of that the `delegate` call has the side effect of defining the `all` method.

*Sidenote:* [YARD (Yay! A Ruby Documentation Tool)](http://yardoc.org/) is programmable and could easily be extended to deduce this (if it doesn't already).

Comment: How can I find out that it's defined by the delegate macro?

Comment: Look at line 440 in that file:                                    class << self # Class methods
 441       **delegate** :find, :first, :first!, :last, :last!, **:all**, :exists?, :any?, :many?, :to => :scoped

Comment: See the source code line you mentioned in your own question. It says:  `delegate … :all, …`

Answer (score 2):

Because they're delegated. Take a look at line #441. The document processor doesn't execute the code and therefore can't handle metaprogramming well.